# I want to identify name , address from given Japanese text using python libraries

Tags: python, cjk, named-entity-recognition

I want to identify name , address from given Japanese text using python libraries
I am in need of NER Japanese model.

Comment: import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load('xx_ent_wiki_sm')
sentence = "私の名前はサイキランです"
doc = nlp(sentence)
print(doc.ents)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Questions seeking software/package recommendations are Off Topic.